# MSE 'mirror' or...?

Tags: discussion, scraper-sites

This may not be terribly important, but while searching with Google for some stuff, I had a few MSE links come up, and then the same things on another site: http://math.troplet.com/

It appears to be a copy of the questions and answers, but without any functionality (i.e., you cannot post or answer a question there). Their copyright page suggests they are a search engine for TV series, but the main page makes it look like they may actually just mirror the entire SE network, i.e., not just MSE.

Any idea what this is?

Comment: Lol. It doesn't even support Latex.

Comment: Why is this still up

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is called a scraper site, and you can report the site to StackExchange as discussed in [this capital-M Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do). As far as I can tell, the site is not following the attribution requirements listed under the [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license [with attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), and as such should be reported.

To copy the relevant information about the reporting process,

> Please [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) directly using the on-site form. Select the "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution" option from the drop-down, and provide as much information as possible. Even if you are reporting an entire site that is scraping many questions, please provide an example of a question on their site and the corresponding question on our site, as well as any Google search terms you used that led you to finding this site. Any other information you might have can be included in the free-form text box.

Comment: Great, thanks! I just reported it and will keep this in mind if I see this again.

Comment: Site still seems to be up